# Cast with (double) or " *1.0 "

Tags: java, double

In this code:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;

double x = (double) a/b;
double x = (1.0*a)/b;
```

The result seems to be the same, or is exatcly the same, i think so.
I used to cast with (double), but for some reason that i don't remember, i passed to use "1.0*"

Which of two is better to use, or whatever?

Comment: which type are `a`  and `b` ?

Comment: Why would they be different?

Comment: This is an very poorly put together question. `or is exatcly the same, i think so` you tell us. You haven't given us enough code to reproduce the problem. `for some reason that i don't remember, i passed to use "1.0*"` what does this even mean? `Which of two is better to use` define "better". `or whatever` why even add this? This needs serious revision to be answerable.

Comment: Try to state the problem a bit better.

Comment: I agree. We can't even tell what the problem is as your issue isn't clearly stated.

Comment: i forgot the 'int'

Comment: @shmosel it's not different, i didn't say this.

Comment: @tnw do you have a opinion about use "1.0* a" or "(double) a", i'm aking that.

Comment: My question is about Good Pratices.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: So, you can't answer if one of two pratices can or can't bring me some problem int the future or if one of two pratices is more maintainable, if one of two is more accepted in a team?

Comment: The first is definitely more common. But these questions are considered off-topic here because they're mostly opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming variables a and b are type int. If you do

```
double x = (1.0*a)/b;
```

then you are not doing a Integer division. When you multiply or divide two numbers and if one of the number is a floating point then you will get a floating point number.
So, 1.0 * a will give you a floating number and that will be 10.0. You are then dividing 10.0 by 3 and as a result the result will be a floating point number.

Same is with the other case. When you do (double) a, then the value of 'a' will be casted to a double and then you divide it with b as, a result you will get a floating point number. Both the approach will give you same answer.

Comment: Ya, i'm know that the result is the same, but my question if is different is not about the result. It's about good pratices.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the cast (double), it makes the code more readable.

Be careful however as, assuming your values a and b are ints, you may not get the right result as it may cast the result of 10/3 which is 3.0. I'm not sure if you ran the program to check this but play around with it.

Comment: No, it may not cast the result. It casts `a` to `double` before performing floating point division (for which the result is a double of course).

Comment: the result is the same, cause the cast is on a and not on a/b.